# Why am I getting an error on QtSpim when I try to accumulate the red values in a pixel for calculating the average

Tags: assembly, mips, qtspim

I have written a MIPS Assembly program that takes in a PPM colour image file and increases the brightness of the image by increasing the values of each RGB value in each pixel by 10. And if the value of any of the RGB values exceeds 255 then it just becomes 255.

When I try run it on QtSpim it says there is an error in the loop when I try to accumulate the red values in the $t2 temporary register, in order to calculate the average of all the red value in the pixels later on.

This is the code I have written for this program :

```
#A program that will increase the RGB value of a PPM colour image by 10.


.data
    original_image:         .asciiz "Select a PPM colour image:\n"
    bright_image:            .asciiz "The brightness increased image is:\n"
    width:                  .word 0
    height:                 .word 0
    max_value:              .word 0


.text
.globl main


main:   #Main is the entry point in the program

        #Open and read input and output files
        li $v0, 13
        la $a0, original_image
        li $a1, 0                               #Read-only mode
        syscall

        #Read PPM header
        li $v0, 14
        move $a0, $v0                           #File descriptor
        la $a1, width
        la $a2, height
        la $a3, max_value
        syscall

        #Calculate the number of pixels
        lw $t0, width
        lw $t1, height
        mul $t0, $t0, $t1

        #Allocate memory for the pixel data
        li $v0, 9
        move $a0, $t0                           #The number of bytes
        syscall
        move $s0, $v0                           #Store address of allocated memory

        #Read the pixel data from memory
        li $v0, 14
        move $a0, $v0                           #File descriptor
        move $a1, $s0                           #Buffer the address
        move $a2, $t0                           #Number of bytes
        syscall

        #Process the pixel data
        li $t2, 0                               #Counter for the average calculation


    #Loop through the pixels and increase the data by 10
    loop:
        lw $t3, 0($s0)                          #Load red value
        addi $t3, $t3, 10                       #Add 10 to red value
        sltiu $t4, $t3, 256                     #Check if value is greater than 255
        addi $t3, $t3, -10                      #Subtract 10 from red value
        and $t4, $t4, 1                         #Convert to 0 or 1
        sll $t4, $t4, 8                         #Shift left to make 0 or 1 to 0 or 256
        add $t3, $t3, $t4                       #Add 0 or 256 to red value
        addi $t2, $t2, $t3                      #Accumulate red value for average calculation
        move $t5, $t3                           #Store new red value

        lw $t3, 4($s0)                          #Load green value
        addi $t3, $t3, 10                       #Add 10 to green value
        sltiu $t4, $t3, 256                     #Check if value is greater than 255
        addi $t3, $t3, -10                      #Subtract 10 from green value
        and $t4, $t4, 1                         #Convert to 0 or 1
        sll $t4, $t4, 8                         #Shift left to make 0 or 1 to 0 or 256
        add $t3, $t3, $t4                       #Add 0 or 256 to green value
        addi $t2, $t2, $t3                      #Accumulate green value for average calculation
        move $t6, $t3                           #Store new green value

        lw $t3, 8($s0)                          #Load blue value
        addi $t3, $t3, 10                       #Add 10 to blue value
        sltiu $t4, $t3, 256                     #Check if value is greater than 255
        addi $t3, $t3, -10                      #Subtract 10 from blue value
        and $t4, $t4, 1                         #Convert to 0 or 1
        sll $t4, $t4, 8                         #Shift left to make 0 or 1 to 0 or 256
        add $t3, $t3, $t4                       #Add 0 or 256 to blue value
        addi $t2, $t2, $t3                      #Accumulate blue value for average calculation
        move $t7, $t3                           #Store new blue value


        #Store new pixel data
        sw $t5, 0($s0)                          #Store new red value
        sw $t6, 4($s0)                          #Store new green value
        sw $t7, 8($s0)                          #Store new blue value

        addi $s0, $s0, 12                       #Move to next pixel
        addi $t0, $t0, -1                       #Decrement counter
        bnez $t0, loop                          #Branch if counter is not zero

        #Open new file for writing
        li $v0, 15
        la $a0, bright_image
        li $a1, 1                               #Write-only mode
        li $a2, 0x1a4                           #File permissions
        syscall

        #Write PPM header
        li $v0, 16
        move $a0, $v0                           #File descriptor
        lw $a1, width
        lw $a2, height
        lw $a3, max_value
        syscall

        #Write pixel data
        li $v0, 15
        move $a0, $v0                           #File descriptor
        move $a1, $s0                           #Buffer address
        move $a2, $t0                           #Number of bytes
        syscall

        #Calculate average of original RGB values
        li $v0, 9
        move $a0, $t2                           #Sum of RGB values
        move $a1, $t0                           #Number of pixels
        syscall
        mtc1 $v0, $f0                           #Move result to FPU register

        #Calculate average of new RGB values
        li $v0, 9
        move $a0, $t2                           #Sum of RGB values
        li $a1, 1                               #Number of pixels
        syscall
        mtc1 $v0, $f2                           #Move result to FPU register

        #Display average of original RGB values
        li $v0, 2
        movt $a0, $f0
        syscall

        #Display average of new RGB values
        li $v0, 2
        movt $a0, $f2
        syscall

        #Exit program
        li $v0, 10
        syscall
```

Please can someone advise me where I went wrong.

I was expecting the program to load on QtSpim but it gave me and error message of :

" spim: (parser) syntax error on line 66 of file C:/Users/increase_brightness.asm
addi $t2, $t2, $t3      #Accumulate red value for average calculation "

Comment: Wrong opcode, use `add` for signed, or `addu` if unsigned/pointer, for use with 3 registers. The `i` forms (suffix `i`, as in `addi` and `addiu`) are for use with two registers and one immediate (constant).  There are some correct examples of using `addi` with 2 registers and one constant in that code.  Since that code has multiple errors in QtSpim and also MARS, it is possible that it was written for a different assembler, but I don't know which.  It does use the standard syscalls for QtSpim and MARS.  Otherwise it looks like it would be an untested program.